# How can I check PHP version if phpinfo() is disabled?

Tags: php

What are some workarounds for checking what version of PHP when phpinfo() is disabled?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- [`phpversion()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php) will return a full version string.
- The [`PHP_VERSION`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#reserved.constants.core) constant also contains the version information.
- Since PHP 5.2.7, there are also constants containing "sub-info" like `PHP_MAJOR_VERSION`, `PHP_MINOR_VERSION`....

Comment: If phpinfo() is disabled, chances are that php_version() is disabled too (it happened to me). Check the PHP_VERSION constant directly, that worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can check the `PHP_VERSION` constant (this is a string) or `PHP_MAJOR_VERSION`, `PHP_MINOR_VERSION`, `PHP_RELEASE_VERSION` for their respective integer values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [softPhpInfo()](https://github.com/jorunkel/softphpinfo) instead which prints also other useful configuration infos. It's an alternative to PHP's built-in `phpinfo()`.

Comment: *which prints also other useful configuration infos* You're answering to something that the OP didn't asked. And why use a package instead of using constants as shown in other answers?

Comment: @A.L: sure, but I came to this question because of the disabled phpinfo function (searching for "phpinfo is disabled") and this was #2 result. So others might find this useful as well.